# Using graph QL and React, how can I divide API by month?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

For example, When there are a lot of data like this:

```
[
  {title:"string" , data:"2022-05-01", amount:10},
  {title:"string" , data:"2022-04-01", amount:10},
  {title:"string" , data:"2022-03-03", amount:10},
  {title:"string" , data:"2022-04-01", amount:10}
]
```

Is there a way to efficiently divide and manage the data every month?
I want to make a monthly list using a filter and manage it.
(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.When I receive object 100 as above,
I would like to manage the data monthly(March and April ....Dec, separately.)

Comment: You could use `.filter()` on the array to pull only those objects for a specific month. However, something tells me it won't be suitable in this scenario. Does your API allow you to send the month info on the request and the backend can filter out the info on it's response?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the backend yet because I'm just studying graph QL. It's better to filter on the back end. I need to find out how to filter on the data in backend. thank you so much..!

Comment: Apart from the title, this looks like a basic JavaScript array-processing question, nothing to do with React or GraphQL?

Comment: Thank for comment.To be honest, I wondered how the backend handles monthly data. If I do it at the front end, it's too inefficient(my opinion). So, I wanted to know  how to manage data by month in backend, but may be my English was not good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you an example for your reference:

```js
let data = [{
    title: "string",
    data: "2022-05-01",
    amount: 10
  },
  {
    title: "string",
    data: "2022-04-01",
    amount: 10
  },
  {
    title: "string",
    data: "2022-03-03",
    amount: 10
  },
  {
    title: "string",
    data: "2022-04-01",
    amount: 10
  }
];
let monthly;
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  monthly=(data.filter(gg => {
    let d = new Date(gg.data);
    return (d.getMonth() == i)
  }));
  if (monthly.length>0){
    console.log(monthly);
  }
}
```